# reinforcing existing header

Tags: carpentry

My house has an existing header, which I believe is somewhat undersized.  For context, it's two-ply 2x10s, 12ft long (but I don't want to get into the sizing calculation here).

I would like to reinforce the header by putting two braces at each end.  These would be pieces of 4x4, about 3ft long, which would be attached at a 45 degree angle at each end of the header, going between the jack studs and the header (attaching to each roughly 2ft from the upper corner).

[image]

Questions:

1. What is the name of a brace like this ?  (I can't seem to google something comparable).
2. What becomes the effective span of the reinforced header ?   It's gotta be better than the original 12ft, but I doubt it's as good as the 8ft between the two braces.
3. What's the best way to attach the braces to the jacks and header ?  I'm imagining large lag bolts (perhaps 5/8" x 8"); install them horizontally and vertically, or straight into the bottom face of each brace (so 45 degree angle to the jacks and header) ?   Some other kind of fasteners ?

Comment: If there's enough load on that header that bending or failure is a concern, lag bolts aren't going to do you a bit of good. You would need shear reinforcement much better than that. You're asking how to implement a flawed solution to an unstated problem. I'd change tack and ask about the actual problem.

Comment: I’m with @isherwood  I think someone once said “For each action, there’s an equal and opposite reaction” or something like that. You don’t want to get into sizing the existing header, but you want to transfer “some” load into the braces and ultimately the posts with some kind of connector. Hmmm...that could be a problem.

Comment: And if you get around to revising the post I'll suggest sistering a steel plate. That would be fairly easy if your beam is tight to the outside; less so if it has a gap in the middle.

Comment: Steel plate is not a half-bad idea.   Probably easier, not withstanding the price of the steel itself.   I imagine it doesn't need to be the full 12ft.   Source of guidelines on sizing this ?

Comment: Normally I spec a channel for this. You need out of plane support for the edges for one, and that also puts more steel where you want it. But it sure seems easier and cheaper to just replace the header with a GLB, LSL, LVL or PSL

Comment: @isherwood Just bolting a piece of steel seems pretty easy to me; replacing the header, not so much.  What do you mean by "out of plane support for the edges" and "spec a channel" ?

Comment: Sorry, jargon, spec = specify or tell you what size or what to use or do. Re support of the edges, think of a long 2x12 header, it would 'roll over' or twist under heavy load. Channel is very thin for its depth. Adding steel to a beam is to add strength and therefore based on the original beam being overloaded. The overload also changes things related to this roll over effect. For efficiently in my design time (client's $) and other reasons, we just spec a channel.

Comment: Thanks.   So just get a piece of channel steel, near as possible to the 3.5" width of the header, and lag it to the bottom of the header ?  One complication: there's 2x4's along the bottom and top of the 2x10s; so need to lag through those into the 2x10s.

Comment: Mount vertically on the side using lag screws such as Simpson SDS. You can put the flanges facing the wood if needed to fit and even make notch or dado into the wood for them, since the steel is carrying the load now (wood and steel are not able to share load, for reasons) we don't care about the wood for vertical load carrying but do want it for other reasons. I can't tell you what size to use, liability etc, and I don't know the loads. But something closer to the depth of the wood should be enough. Also, your steel supplier might be able to help since he is not bound by my restrictions.

Comment: Not concerned about getting the sizing just right - just doing ANYTHING will be huge.   This thing has been fine for years, with no signs of excessive bending.   But ... we haven't had anything like this area's design load of 20psf of snow.    Maybe I just put a temporary brace under the middle of the thing if it ever snows again here :-)

Comment: Oh, I should add, this is on an open porch.  So both sides of the header, as well as the inner side of the jack studs, are fully exposed.  Also, the builder used treated wood.

Comment: “For each action, there’s an equal and opposite reaction”: Sir Issac Newton's Third Law.

Comment: That's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. this is called a knee brace
2. You mean the span not the bearing width. Assuming the brace to be fully effective, the effective span is less than the span between the knee braces. The reason is too complected to explain in detail here. For design, you could be conservative and just use the distance between the braces
3. I usually suggest lag screws. The screws will be in shear, not withdrawal, so the length only needs to be long enough to get through the brace and into the main member a few inches

This isn't a very good solution. You'll create bending in your trimmer and king stud that will reduce their design strength. Knee braces generally aren't used to reduce the span, they are for lateral (sideways) strength so that it doesn't fall over. Think about a gazebo

Your best solution is to replace the header with a stronger one. It can be of the same(ish) size and therefore not reducing the opening under it. Good options include glue laminated beam and manufactured lumber such as LSL, LVL and PSL.